# Function having sub functions and their arguments as arguments

Tags: python, function

I would like to build a pandas random dataframe. To fulfill that purpose I need a Python function taking as arguments :

- numpy distributions
- their arguments

For example :

distribution 1 : normal | arguments : means = 0 , standard dev = 1 , size = 100

distribution 2 : uniform | arguments : low = 0 , high = 1 , size = 100

etc...

I do not know in advance what will be the different distributions and their arguments.

The main function will then generate random samples of the distributions using each corresponding arguments.

I have tried something like :

```
import numpy as np

def myfun( **kwargs ) :
    for k , v in kwargs.items() :
        print( k )
        print( v )
```

When I call that function with these arguments :

```
myfun( fun_1 = 'np.random.normal' , arg_1 = { 'loc' : 0 , 'scale' : 1 , 'size' : 7 } ,
       fun_2 = 'np.random.uniform' , arg_2 = { 'low' : 0 , 'high' : 1 , 'size' : 7 } )
```

The output is :

```
fun_1
np.random.normal
arg_1
{'loc': 0, 'scale': 1, 'size': 7}
fun_2
np.random.uniform
arg_2
{'low': 0, 'high': 1, 'size': 7}
```

But my purpose is not to print the desired distributions and their associated parameters but to generate a sample for each distributions.

Comment: Is `myfun` supposed to return, say, `np.random.normal` called with the args defined in `arg_1`?

Comment: Do the functions need to be strings, or would passing them as functions (without quotes) be sufficient? Like instead of `'np.random.normal'` you'd pass `np.random.normal`

Comment: Sorry for my example. Functions should be passed as functions, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Note, the functions should be functions, not strings, for this implementation to work

If you want to return the function called with a set of `kwargs`, you're pretty close. I would use a positional argument for `func`, then you can pass `kwargs` into `func`, which is a bit more explicit:

```py
def myfunc(func, **kwargs):
    return func(**kwargs)
```

Then, you could wrap each pair of `func, **kwargs` as tuples, and do a for loop:

```py
# This would be called like
somelist = [(np.random.normal, { 'loc' : 0 , 'scale' : 1 , 'size' : 7 }),
            (np.random.uniform , { 'low' : 0 , 'high' : 1 , 'size' : 7 })]

results = []

# append results to a list
for func, kwargs in somelist:
    results.append(myfunc(func, **kwargs))
```

By doing it this way, you don't have to worry about what you *name* any of your variables, and it's a bit more readable. You know that the loop will be dealing with pairs of items, in this case `func, kwarg` pairs, and your function can handle those explicitly

### Handling the string calls

So there are a few ways to accomplish this task that are a bit more tricky, but overall shouldn't be horrible. You'll need to modify `myfunc` to handle the function name:

```py
# func is now a string, unlike above

def myfunc(func, **kwargs):
    # function will look like module.class.function
    # so split on '.' to get each component. The first will 
    # be the parent module in global scope, and everything else
    # is collected into a list
    mod, *f = func.split('.') # f is a list of sub-modules like ['random', 'uniform']
    # func for now will just be the module np
    func = globals().get(mod)
    for cls in f:
        # get each subsequent level down, which will overwrite func to
        # first be np.random, then np.random.uniform
        func = getattr(func, cls)
    return func(**kwargs)
```

The reason I'm using `globals().get(mod)` is a) I'm assuming you might not always be using the same module, and b) calling a renamed import from `sys.modules` will yield a `KeyError`, which isn't what you want:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

sys.modules['np'] # KeyError

sys.modules['numpy']
# <module 'numpy.random' from '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py'>

# globals avoids the naming conflict
globals()['np']
# <module 'numpy.random' from '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py'>
```

Then `getattr(obj, attr)` will return each subsequent module:

```py
import numpy as np

getattr(np, 'random')
# <module 'numpy.random' from '/Users/mm92400/anaconda3/envs/new36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py'>

# the dotted access won't work directly
getattr(np, 'random.uniform')
# AttributeError
```

So, in total:

```py
import numpy as np

func, kwargs = ('np.random.normal', { 'loc' : 0 , 'scale' : 1 , 'size' : 7 })

myfunc(func, **kwargs)

array([ 0.83276777,  2.4836389 , -1.07492873, -1.20056678, -0.36409906,
       -0.76543554,  0.90191746])
```

And you can just extend that to the code in the first section

Comment: The numpy functions can't be strings for this to work - you'd get `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Otherwise this is a good answer

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy ah, right, I'd have to `eval` or do something weird, I'll see if I can edit it to make sense

Comment: You don't have to `eval()` it, and you shouldn't because `eval()` is dangerous - but just referring to them without the quotes should work, since that invokes the reference to the function in the first place. `np.random.normal` instead of `'np.random.normal'`

Comment: Ideally, yes, you would avoid eval at all costs, but OP specifically asked for it as string inputs. I'll ask for a clarification

Comment: That problem is probably out-of-scope for this question, but for reference the better way of handling it would probably be to parse the module/method names and [try to call the function by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string) based on that

Comment: Correct, you'd have to call `np` from `sys.modules` or something similar and traverse it using `getattr` calls

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy added handling the string calls in an edit, not sure if it's the best practice way, but it works for the moment

Answer (score 0):

You can design a function that takes other functions as inputs, and executes them. That's what the `**` operator does:

```
def myfun(**kwargs):
    kwargs['fun_1'](**kwargs['arg_1'])  # calls the function kwargs[fun_1] with the keyword args given in kwargs[arg_1]
    kwargs['fun_2'](**kwargs['arg_2'])
```

You would then specify your kwargs like such:

```
myfun(fun_1=np.random.normal, 
      arg_1={'loc': 0, 'scale': 1, 'size': 7},
      fun_2=np.random.uniform,
      arg_2={'low': 0, 'high': 1, 'size': 7},
     )
```

Note how `np.random.normal` isn't in quotes - we refer to the actual function, by reference, but without calling it yet (because we want to do that in `myfun()`, not now).

I don't think there's an official name for this operator (`*` for lists and `**` for dicts), but I call it the unpacking operator because it *unpacks* a data structure into function arguments.

---

It's usually *safer* to state explicit named parameters, in this situation - you'll need to come up with a pattern so that people using your function know how they're supposed to name their keywords.

Comment: @GrennCloakGuy In myfun you treat 2 sub functions calls but you do not know in advance the number of sub functions to call.

Comment: That's why I said you'd need to come up with a pattern for keywords - then you could loop through `kwargs` and take functions and arguments that correspond to each other. @C.Nivs's answer above is better, though